# Simple html dom - other result than expected

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I try to retrieve info from a webpage using simple_html_dom, like this:

```
<?PHP
include_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php');
$urlpart="http://w2.brreg.no/motorvogn/";
$url = "http://w2.brreg.no/motorvogn/heftelser_motorvogn.jsp?regnr=BR15597";
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       if(preg_match('*dagb*',$element)) {
       $result=$urlpart.$element->href;

       $resultcontent=file_get_contents($result);
       echo $resultcontent;

       }

?>
```

The $result variable first gives me this URL:
http://w2.brreg.no/motorvogn/dagbokutskrift.jsp?dgbnr=2011365320&embnr=0&regnr=BR15597

When accessing the above URL with my browser, i get the content i expect.

When retrieving the content with $resultcontent, i get a different result, where it says in norwegian "Invalid input".

Any ideas why?

Comment: Oh my, that's a tough one, I tried many ways to download the page but still  getting the same error... The weird thing is that when you replace `$result` with the excpected link, it displays the correct output !!! So it maybe some hidden char in the extracted link, I personally couldnt find any :-/ what a puzzle xD

Comment: It was a tough one, but solved by the answers below! Thanks for trying to help out!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       if(preg_match('*dagb*',$element)) {
       $result=$urlpart.$element->href;
       $resultcontent=file_get_contents(html_entity_decode($result));
       echo $resultcontent;

       }
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your URL query parameter.

```
http://w2.brreg.no/motorvogn/dagbokutskrift.jsp?dgbnr=2011365320&embnr=0&regnr=BR15597
```

The string '&reg' in the URL will be converted to Symbol ® in file_get_contents function which stops you from getting the actual result.

You can use `html_entity_decode` function in line #11

```
$resultcontent=file_get_contents(html_entity_decode($result));
```